# jQuery dialog box not working properly on Android

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I am having an issue with the jQuery dialog box on specific versions of Android. I have used phonegap to build my app, I have noticed it works on all browsers and Android 4.0.3.

However, when i try to load it in say 2.2.3, then the scroll does not seem to work. Can someone please have a look at my code below to see why not, I have done lots of research and tried various things suchs as ScrollX: true, overflow: scroll etc. I call the function on click of a button:

```
var $upgrade = $('<div></div>')
.html('<p>LOTS OF TEXT GOES HERE</p>')
.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height:270,
    width: 400,
    title: 'Upgrade'
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the simplest and effective solution was to simply reduce the jquery font-size down to 11px, which fitted nicely within the set box size and still readable.

```
<div style="font-size:11px;"></div>
```